# Align text to the left regardless of how much text is shown in a VStack in SwifUI

Tags: swiftui

How can I force the text to always align to the left regardless of how big is the text?

What I get is what's shown in the first image, what I need is to align it to look like the second image.

```
struct GeneralTest: View {
    let fruits = ["Apple", "Oranges from Californ"]
    
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(fruits, id: \.self) { fruit in
                HStack{
                    Image(systemName: "pencil.circle.fill")
                        .frame(width: 65)
                        .foregroundColor(.blue)
                        .background(.yellow)
                    
                    VStack(alignment: .leading){
                        Text(fruit)
                            .font(.title3)
                            .foregroundColor(Color.blue)
                        
                        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                            Text("Some text")
                                .foregroundColor(Color.gray)
                                .font(.caption)
                            Text("Some text:")
                                .foregroundColor(Color.gray)
                                .font(.caption)
                            Text("Some Text:")
                                .foregroundColor(Color.gray)
                                .font(.caption)
                        }
                    }
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                    .background(.yellow)
                    
                    Button{
                        
                    }label:{
                        Image( systemName: "circle.hexagongrid.circle")
                            .padding()
                            .background(Color.yellow)
                            .foregroundColor( Color.blue)
                            .cornerRadius(30)
                            .overlay(
                                Circle()
                                    .stroke( Color.gray, lineWidth: 0.5)
                            )
                    }
                    NavigationLink(destination: SomeView()){
                        
                    }
                    .frame(maxWidth: 10)
                }
            } // ForEach end
        }
        .background(Color.pink)
        .listStyle(GroupedListStyle())
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap the "fruit" `VStack` inside an `HStack`, then use a `Spacer()` to move the text to the left.

Like this:

```
ForEach(fruits, id: \.self) { fruit in
    HStack{
        Image(systemName: "pencil.circle.fill")
            .frame(width: 65)
            .foregroundColor(.blue)
            .background(.yellow)
        
        // The VStack is inside an HStack
        HStack {
            VStack(alignment: .leading){
                Text(fruit)
                    .font(.title3)
                    .foregroundColor(Color.blue)
                
                VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                    Text("Some text")
                        .foregroundColor(Color.gray)
                        .font(.caption)
                    Text("Some text:")
                        .foregroundColor(Color.gray)
                        .font(.caption)
                    Text("Some Text:")
                        .foregroundColor(Color.gray)
                        .font(.caption)
                }
            }

            // This Spacer() will push the VStack to the left
            Spacer()
        }
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
        .background(.yellow)
        
        Button{
            
        }label:{
            Image( systemName: "circle.hexagongrid.circle")
                .padding()
                .background(Color.yellow)
                .foregroundColor( Color.blue)
                .cornerRadius(30)
                .overlay(
                    Circle()
                        .stroke( Color.gray, lineWidth: 0.5)
                )
        }
        NavigationLink(destination: SomeView()){
            
        }
        .frame(maxWidth: 10)
    }
} // ForEach end
```

Comment: Shoot, I didn't think of it. Thanks a lot!